# How does lazydata loading work in R package installation?

Tags: r, lazy-loading, r-package

I want to expose data that is already published in my data/ directory of my R package skeleton. See this link for "External data" sharing basics: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html.

My data is stored in .txt format. If you didn't want to load the data via lazy loading, which would just be loaded by loading the R package require(myRpackage) and then doing data(datasetName)... you can read the data in normally using many of the read.table(), read.csv2() functions in base R.

My dataset is called "publishedData.txt" in this example, and can be loaded as below, which works beautifully:

```
tmp = read.table("/dir/to/R/package/data/publishedData.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
```

However, when I go to re-install my R package with this new shiny & wonderful data, I get the following fail message, over and over (see pasted below).

```
Downloading GitHub repo myGitRepo/myRpackage@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/myGitRepo/myRpackage/zipball/master
Installing myRpackage
library='/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library' -- 
install-tests 
* installing *source* package ‘myRpackage’ ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = 
dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 215 elements
ERROR: lazydata failed for package ‘myRpackage’
* removing 
‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/myRpackage’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Note, the above Github repo isn't real. I'm writing a generic post, so don't try to install this fake R package yourself.

My question: How do I debug lazydata load, when I don't know how lazydata load is performed? i.e., what code decides if the data in my publishedData.txt in my data/ folder is "A-OK", versus "Not okay"? I know they are using scan(), yet it should know that sep="\t" in a .txt file, and other than that, I'm not sure what's tripping it up?

Things I've tried:

1. I've scrubbed my header names as best as I can (e.g., removing non-alphabetical characters from column or rownames strings).
2. I've also removed any other column besides the rownames column that has string data in it instead of numerical data, just in case stringsAsFactors is set to default of TRUE in lazydata loading (which would slow down things by a lot).
3. Also, I've restarted R after each re-install attempt...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out a way to get this to work, without having to actually understand what was tripping it up.

Say your dataset loads using read.table(), but doesn't reinstall with lazydata load as described above. Chances are, your headers / rownames are off. A quick solution is just to do this:

```
# Load your data into R the way it works
tmp = read.table("/dir/to/R/package/data/publishedData.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
# Write data to same file with these arguments
write.table(tmp, file="/dir/to/R/package/data/publishedData.txt", sep="\t", row.names = TRUE, col.names = TRUE)
```

Then, update your Github repo with git, and then try to reinstall R package. It will work this time around! The difference in the .txt file was the header for the col.names - the first "column" does not have a label associated with the rownames. It just starts with the col.name for column 1 of your data matrix. Then, in row 2, the row name for row 2 starts, then all the data comes next. So technically, row 1 has 1 less element in it than row 2, if you were to parse this data using a different method.

Hope it helps someone else. :-)